# delete paperclip directory in :id_partition format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
has_attached_file :asset,
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension", 
:url => "/system/:class/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

I have the above code in my model.  This makes a path like /public/system/uploads/000/000/001, where 1 would be the id number of the record.  Now the directory contains the original image but it also contains a thumbnail as well.  When I want to delete the record the original file gets deleted but the directory remains, since the thumbnail still exists in the directory. How do I go about deleting the directory entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an observer with `rails g observer Upload` and make it look like

```
class UploadObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe Upload

  def before_destroy(record)
    FileUtils.rm_rf File.dirname(Upload.find(record).upload.path)
  end
end
```

and remember to register the observer in `application.rb`with `config.active_record.observers = :upload_observer`